# How does the Windows GetMessage function work in C

Tags: c, windows, hook, systems-programming, getmessage

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Keyboard hook handle
HHOOK keyboardHook;

// Callback function declaration for keyboard events
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) lParam;
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
            // Here you can handle the key press
            printf("Key Pressed: %d\n", p->vkCode);
            // Example: Quit if the user presses the 'Q' key
            if(p->vkCode == 'Q') {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            }
        }
    }
    // return CallNextHookEx(keyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main() {
    MSG msg;
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    // Set the low-level keyboard hook
    keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, hInstance, 0);

    GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);

    // Remove the keyboard hook when the application exits
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHook);

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, when I run with `GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)`, character codes print to the console. When I get rid of `GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)`, it closes the hook right after it sets it and exits the program (i.e. nothing prints to the console). Additionally, when I use Sleep(1000) or Sleep in a while loop, nothing prints to console. So, what is GetMessage actually doing here?

For example, when it receives a message (key press), it calls the callback function? I don't understand how GetMessage connects to the hook and callback function.

Comment: The [`GetMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) blocks the calling process until a message has been received. If you don't have it your program will just continue to the end of the `main` function and exit.

Comment: GetMessage is used to retrieve messages from the queue. She is blocking, as long as there is no message, she waits. When it returns, the MSG structure is filled with the message information.

Comment: Typically, in a GUI program it will be `WinMain()` where you will have a message handling loop, which directs the message to your callback handler, set when you create the window class. For example `while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) { TranslateMessage(&Msg); DispatchMessage(&Msg); }`

Comment: Yes, it's totally not straightforward like calling `getch()` and observing the return value. I didn't get clear on it until coding windows key-fetching routines and testing them with lots of `printf()` for many hours.  Explanations and code examples are abundant on the [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/) site for every message-related API.   But still, nothing gelled for me until lots of coding and testing.  And keyboard messages can be buried in mouse and other messages too.  It can get crowded and non-simple, immensely.

Comment: GetMessage is *required* for a program that uses WH_KEYBOARD_LL, it allows the OS to gain control and make the callbacks to KeyboardProc().  A message loop is the more traditional approach.  In addition, here it stops the main() method from completing too soon.